# How to deploy a file in UWP FullTrusted app

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, uwp

I created Install Package project 1809 version and added two apps UWP and Console. I have two applications inside: UWP and console app bridge in full trusted mode. In UWP app I have xml settings file? so I added it in Install Package project too. Is there any way to deploy this file in LocalState folder?

Answer (score 1):

> so I added it in Install Package project too. Is there any way to deploy this file in LocalState folder?

Sure, you could use [`CopyAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.copyasync?view=winrt-19041) method to copy the file to `LocalState` from package project when app start.

```
private async void CopyFileToLocal()
{
    try
    {
        var file = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("ss.xml");
        if (file != null)
        {
            await file.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! I know about that method but I actually need to copy file only after deploying because second programm starting earlier before UWP app can use settings file.

Comment: I'm afraid  you can't place the file into the local during deploying.  current there is not such api could approach.

Comment: *second programm starting earlier before UWP app can use settings file.* I think you could copy it into local when  app's splash start. Please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/add-a-splash-screen)

Comment: Could you share the detail about why you want to deploy file to local storage when app installation ?

Comment: I think you could make some condition to detect if local folder contains setting file, if not copy it form package folder, then load it.

Comment: My service starts before the UWP of the application, but it must use the settings that the user can enter. If the service is started for the first time before the UWP starts, the service will refer to a nonexistent file.

Comment: I think you need to make a placeholder setting file when uwp can't response for the first time for your server.

Comment: If above answer or comments is helpful, please consider mark it, and if  you do want to deploy the file into local storage during app installation please feel free post your requirement with windows feed back hub.